# Mobile graphics cards - will they cope with the most demanding games

Tags: graphics-card

I'm in the process of thinking about upgrading my laptop.  I haven't been gaming for a while, but with a nice shiny new laptop, I would probably look to get into a few games again :)

I'm a bit out of the loop, but would a mobile graphics card (something like a Nvidia GT 635M) cope with the demands of a modern game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but keep in mind that a laptop is a laptop, and if it's not an Alienware or some sort of dedicated laptop for gaming, it won't run top-notch on the most demanding games and i'm talking about maxed-out settings on video settings. A friend of mine was able to play on a Lenovo with Nvidia GT 635M Crysis 2 with medium settings and it really looked astonishing!

Of course it depends on the other components as well as i won't recommend anything lower than a good Intel i5 for gaming purposes (good meaning above 2.1 ghz prefferable 2.4 or more).

And am offtopic tip: pick a screen that is not very glossy since sunlight will make it hard to see (i'm pretty much struggling with dark areas sometimes).

**EDIT:**

I highly recommend [THIS](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-640M.71579.0.html) website for comparison between notebook graphics cards it really helped me pick a nice one for me.

Comment: Alienware is NOT what it used to be anymore. Since Dell took over the brand became even more overpriced. I would strongly recommend against buying anything alienware, unless money is absolutely no issue.

Comment: @Kevin it might be so, I never used one so I can't know for sure, my point was that if the laptop is not dedicated for gaming it is possible that it won't run maxed-out settings. But specs should always be checked carefully :)

Comment: Thanks for that, no real worries about getting an Alienware machine either way!  Pockets not quite that deep.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't a 635M be a low-end GPU? Shouldn't you rather go for a 640M/740M (mid-range) or better instead? Just stay away from the 670M and 675M and choose the 670MX or 675MX instead.

Comment: An i7 CPU is hardly any better for gaming than an i5 - the only difference is hyperthreading, and almost no games can take advantage of that.

Comment: @kotekzot corrected you,re right!